# incrementing a variable for each non-NaN value in a column with string datatype

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

The issue I have is that I want to increment the value of a variable when the value of a pandas column dataframe is not NaN knowing that the column contains string datatypes.

```
`def indicateur_iov2(row):
    row["IOV2"] = 0.0
    row["IOV2"] = (
        row["Bon alimentaire"]
        + row["Bon Hygiène"]
        + row["Ticket Hammam / Pour les personnes en rue "]
        + row["Ticket Restaurant / Pour les personnes en rue "]
        + row["Kits cuisine / Pour les personnes avec un hébergement"]
    )

    if row["Kit couchage / Pour les personnes avec un hébergement"] == "Oui":
        row["IOV2"] += 1.0

    if str(row["Service Médical "]) != "":
        row["IOV2"] += 1.0

    if str(row["Service Psychosociale "]) != "":
        row["IOV2"] += 1.0

    return row["IOV2"]`
```

This is the code I wrote, the function works fine until the second if statement, when it does not increment the value of row["IOV2"] even if the conditions are true.

Comment: Please post sample of your data and expected output

Comment: Why are you successively assigning row["IOV2"] to different values? Only the second will be used.